# Azure Cosmos DB - Maximum number of 'Collection' per account exceeded. Current configured quota 100

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I'm trying to create on Azure Cosmos DB with MongoDB driver, a new collection.
I've reached the limit of 100 collection for account cause it's a serverless account.
Now I've deleted some old databases and collection a couple of days ago to free up some space, but I continue to receive the same error.
What I'm supposed to do to solve the issue?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a product support / quota question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serverless accounts are limited to 100 collections per account, documented here in service quotas, https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/concepts-limits#serverless-1.

If you are expecting more than 100 collections across all databases in the account, I'd recommend using the MongoDB vCore service. Unlike the RU-based model this is single-instance, VM-based, and can be a better fit when migrating existing MongoDB workloads, particularly those with large numbers of small collections. You can start here to learn more, https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/vcore/introduction.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for the information. In our case it's just a test account: we create many database and collections related to some application units, and then we delete those application unit. For the moment we didn't have managed the deletion of the mongo collections, but  all of them are for testing purposes. Now I've deleted manually about 40 collections, but the error still there

Comment: It can take a while for ARM resources to fully delete. This is a common issue across all Azure resources. This can make it difficult to do rapid creation and deletions. Unfortunately the way ARM works, the deletion is a fire and forget. There's nothing really that lets you know when you can recreate the resource.

Comment: One possible workaround is to try using the Cosmos emulator. Unfortunately, if you're running on an M1 or M2 chip emulator is not yet supported.  Hopefully somehting here will help.

Comment: one other suggestion is to create new serverless accounts.

Comment: oh, ok thanks, now makes a bit more sense! We will wait a bit, just to test it, and then probably it's better to create a new account yes. Thanks again